# set mail value according to name value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table, with 2 fields, one is "Name" and the HTML class is "name", the other is "Email" with HTML Class: "mail".

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">User Email</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="name">Albert Einstein</td>
      <td class="mail"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

So lets say i have a Mail List like this:

- **Name**: Albert Einstein, **Mail**: "albert@company.com"
- **Name**: Isaac Newton, **Mail**: "inewton@company.com"
- **Name**: Alice Newton, **Mail**: "anewton@company.com"

What i want is to set the value of mail field, according to the name field.

This Javascript code Shared from [@Ganesan San](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8301995/ganesan-san), Seems to almost do the job:

```
var emails = ["albert@company.com", "inewton@company.com", "anewton@company.com"];
var name_elements = document.querySelectorAll("td.name");
var mail_element = document.querySelectorAll("td.mail");
for (i = 0; i < name_elements.length; i++) {
    var current_element = name_elements[i];
    var name = current_element.textContent;
    for (j = 0; j < emails.length; j++) {
        if (emails[j].indexOf(name) != -1) {
            mail_element[i].textContent = emails[j];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work with Capital Letters or Spaces in Names, so how can we fix this code to make it work with Capital Letters and spaces between first and last name? also to detect which email belongs to Persons with similar email, See example :

1. Name: Isaac Newton, Mail: "inewton@company.com"
2. Name: Alice Newton, Mail: "anewton@company.com"

Thanks to [@Alexander Higgins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624988/alexander-higgins) and [@Tushar Vaghela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385267/tushar-vaghela). both answers works great.

Comment: What is the format of the e-mail ? Full name ? Intital + full name ? What if I enter `Einstein` ?

Comment: @Weedoze see code: var emails = ["albert@company.com", "inewton@company.com", "anewton@company.com"]; Intital + last name, but it can variate, Also the Name Format will be always the same, First and Last Name

Comment: `albert@company.com` is not initial + last name... How can it variate ?

Comment: @Weedoze When i say variate, means it can be: aeinstein@company.com, einstein@company.com, albert.einstein@company.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with Capitalization, you can convert your string to lower case using `.toLowerCase()`

Then you need to break you names up into parts and try to find a match for the email.

You can use `split(' ')` to break a string into an array of words using a space for the delimiter.

From here you can get the first name and the last name.

You can take the first character of the first name and combine that with the last to check for addresses in the form of First Initial + LastName + '@' + Domain.

If that fails, and you want to check just by first name the combine First Name + '@' + Domain.

On a side note, in your original code you don't need to loop through all elements check `.indexOf` in each iteration. As shown below, you can check `.indexOf` only one time in the loop.

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="2">User Email</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="name">Albert Einstein</td>
      <td class="mail"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="name">Isaac Newton</td>
      <td class="mail"></td>
   </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="name">Alice Newton</td>
      <td class="mail"></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>

var emails = ["albert@company.com", "inewton@company.com", "anewton@company.com"];
var name_elements = document.querySelectorAll("td.name");
var mail_element = document.querySelectorAll("td.mail");
for (i = 0; i < name_elements.length; i++) {
    var current_element = name_elements[i];
    var name = current_element.textContent.toLowerCase();
    var nameParts= name.split(' ');
    var fName= nameParts[0];
    var fInitial= name[0];
    var lastName= name.split(' ')[1];
    var possibleFormats = [
       fInitial + lastName + '@company.com', 
       fName  + lastName + '@company.com',
       fName + '.' + lastName + '@company.com', 
       fName + '@company.com',
       ]
    var idx=-1;
    for(var k=0; idx<0 && k<possibleFormats.length; k++)
    {

        idx= emails.indexOf(possibleFormats[k]);
        console.log(idx);
    }
    if (idx>-1)
    {
       mail_element[idx].textContent = emails[idx]
    } else {
       console.log('Failed: ' + emailToFind);
    }

}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, just one last questions, what happens if email is albert.einstein@company.com?

Comment: Change the  `emailToFind` variable to your needs. For that it would be `fInitial + '.' +lastName + '@company.com';` If you are going to be search for combinations I would say make an array.

Comment: I understand, Thanks for the Help.

Comment: I modified the code to use an array of possible formats. You can add to that array if you need to.

Comment: Noted,Thanks.  just an observation. after the use of the array, now the email fields of Isaac and Alice Newton are showing empty fields

Comment: Fixed, had to change the inner array variable from i to k.

Comment: Another Observation,  in the real html code i'm using, there's only 1 td class name, and 1 td class mail, i use a database query to get the name field value,  the code works fine with the first mail listed in the javascript code, but when the name field value is another then Albert Einstein, im getting a blank field, for example Alice newton is the 3rd email in the: "email" variable, so when the query result is: Alice Newton, i get a blank field, but if i move anewton@company.com email to the first "email" variable. the code works

Comment: Try running the script inside of  `$(document).ready`. If you still have problems you should open a new question and put the actual HTML of the table,that is begin rendered and the actual script you are using in the question. Also explain how the HTML is being rendered on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```js
var names = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
var mails = document.getElementsByClassName('mail');

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  var namelist = (names[i].innerText).toLowerCase().split(" ");
  var fname = namelist[0].substring(0, 1);
  var lname = namelist[namelist.length - 1];
  mails[i].innerHTML = fname + lname + '@company.com';
}
```

```css
table {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>User</td>
    <td>Email</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Albert Einstein</td>
    <td class="mail"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Isaac Newton</td>
    <td class="mail"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Alice Newton</td>
    <td class="mail"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Alice MiddleName Newton</td>
    <td class="mail"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help,  Already mark the first reply as the answer. but adding this answer as a mention in the original post, so it can count as alternative to the first

Comment: No Problem, this is generic solution where you can enter any name and it will use combination of first and last name even if middle name is mentioned. You can upvote it, if you find this useful. :)

Comment: Cant Up vote right now, my reputation is level 10, need 15. but i'll when i get to 15

Comment: No need friend, Thanks!